# Casting a string to short from a file

Tags: c#

**I have 2 questions!**

**The first question...**

I'm download a string from a file using a StreamReader and a WebRequest. Let's assume I've received the following:

```
Test=0x01
Stack=0x03
Recv=0x0B
```

Now, I do the following to split them all.

```
var result = Regex.Split(file, "\r\n|\r|\n");

        foreach (string op in result)
        {
            string[] splitop = Regex.Split(op, "=");
            RecvOpcodes.Add(new Opcode(splitop[1], short.Parse(splitop[0])));
        }
```

Opcode receives argument of String, Short. For example, the first one would be Test,0x01.

The problem is, it fails to parse for some reason. It says input string wasn't in correct format, why's that?

**The second question..**

I have a list.

```
    public static List<Opcode> SendOpcodes = new List<Opcode>();
```

Opcode is a class of String, Short.

```
 public class Opcode
{
    private string name;
    private short header;

    public Opcode(string nm, short hd)
    {
        name = nm;
        header = hd;
    }
}
```

Now.. I want to be able to get the short by only using the name of the Opcode. For example, if I have an item in that list:

```
Migrate 0x0B  (Migrate is the string, 0x0B is the short)
```

I want to get the 0x0B only by using the Migrate name, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You should split this into two questions =]

Comment: @Sean Well, I don't want to overload by asking 2 questions, so while they're here - why not answer both? Also, your comment is kindof useless.

Comment: I was just saying it before someone else did. The rules are one question per.... Question.

Comment: @Sean Oh, I'm sorry. I am new!

Comment: short.Parse(splitop[0]) should be short.Parse(splitop[1]). splittop[0] is "Test"

Answer (score 3):

Just replace

```
RecvOpcodes.Add(new Opcode(splitop[1], short.Parse(splitop[0])));
```

with

```
RecvOpcodes.Add(new Opcode(splitop[1], Convert.ToInt16(splitop[0],16)));
```

For more info: [Convert Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To convert a hex string to a short, you can use the following overload:

```
short myShort = Convert.ToInt16(hexString, 16);
```

The documentation for this function is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wxkt09k.aspx), and there is an article that deals with converting between hex and numeric values [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx).

So your code should look like this for the first part:

```
var result = Regex.Split(file, "\r\n|\r|\n");

foreach (string op in result)
{
    string[] splitop = Regex.Split(op, "=");
    RecvOpcodes.Add(new Opcode(splitop[0], Convert.ToInt16(splitop[1], 16))); // splitop[0] will contain Test, Stack and Recv; splitop[1] will contain 0x01, 0x03, 0x0B
}
```

To get the `Opcode` with the name `Migrate`, you can add a reference to `System.Linq` and use the `.First()` method:

```
using System.Linq;

.....

public static List<Opcode> SendOpcodes = new List<Opcode>();

.....

SendOpcodes.Add(new Opcode("Migrate", 11));

Opcode desiredOpcode = SendOpcodes.First(opcode => opcode.Name == "Migrate");
```

If you don't know whether or not the `Opcode` is in the list, you can use the `FirstOrDefault` method instead, then check for null (default value for a user-defined class is null):

```
Opcode desiredOpcode = SendOpcodes.FirstOrDefault(opcode => opcode.Name == "Migrate");

if (desiredOpcode != null)
{
    // do what you want next in here
}
```

You can get an introduction to Linq and lambdas [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) and Linq in general [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx).